# Java: Google Calendar API

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm playing with the google calendar API. Out of curiosity I didn't use the Google libraries, so I can write it all myself.
I can't make a new calendar.
The authentication is working because this get request is working: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

For making a new calendar I used: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert

I wrote:

```js
try {           
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS,false);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList");
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); //authentication
    httppost.addHeader("Host", "googleapis.com");

    StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"id\": \"TestSchedule\",\"defaultReminders\":[{\"method\": \"popup\",\"minutes\":10}]}");
    httppost.setEntity(params);

    //EXECUTE REQUEST
    HttpResponse postResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    //RESPONSE
    HttpEntity entity = postResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
    }
    httppost.releaseConnection();

} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Further the scope to get the right token is: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
This should be correct. I think the problem is in the body of my post request?

Thus, get requests are working so I assume my authentication procedure is correct and I get a correct token. Doing this post request instead of the get request results is a 302 response code. The new URL I get is the main page of google, according to the reference pages I should get a calendar resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following code working. please u can check it now. 



      {
       DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS,false);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList");
        httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList");
        //httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); //authentication
       // httppost.addHeader("Host", "googleapis.com");

       /* StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"id\":}");
        httppost.setEntity(params);*/

        //EXECUTE REQUEST
        HttpResponse postResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        //RESPONSE
        HttpEntity entity = postResponse.getEntity();
        String responseBody1 = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        logger.debug(responseBody1);
       }
```